# Scikit NaN or infinity error message

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nan

I'm importing some data from a csv file. The file has nan values flagged with text 'NA'.
I import the data with:

```
X = genfromtxt(data, delimiter=',', dtype=float, skip_header=1)
```

I the use this code to replace nan with a previosly calculated column mean.

```
inds = np.where(np.isnan(X))
X[inds]=np.take(col_mean,inds[1])
```

I then run a couple of checks and get empty arrays:

```
np.where(np.isnan(X))
np.where(np.isinf(X))
```

Finally I run a scikit classifier:

```
RF = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs=-1,verbose=2)
RF.fit(X, y)
```

and get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\m&g\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 257, in fit
    check_ccontiguous=True)
  File "C:\Users\m&g\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 233, in check_arrays
    _assert_all_finite(array)
  File "C:\Users\m&g\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 27, in _assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError("Array contains NaN or infinity.")
ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.
```

Any ideas why it is telling me that there are NaN or infinity?
I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895502/scikit-learn-valueerror-array-contains-nan-or-infinity) and tried to run:

```
RF.fit(X.astype(float), y.astype(float))
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: What does `np.max(np.abs(X))` return?

Comment: np.max(np.abs(X)) = 8.9932064170227995e+41

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scikit-learn's decision trees cast their input to `float32` for efficiency, but your values won't fit in that type:

```
>>> np.float32(8.9932064170227995e+41)
inf
```

The solution is to standardize prior to fitting a model with `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`. Don't forget to `transform` prior to predicting. You can use a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` to combine standardization and classification in a single object:

```
rf = Pipeline([("scale", StandardScaler()),
               ("rf", RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2))])
```

Or, with the current dev version/next release:

```
rf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                   RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2))
```

(I admit the error message could be improved.)

Answer (score 4):

I come across this problem as well. But on the contrary, my problem is that there are some 'NaN' in the array.

Here is how to fix it.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
X = Imputer().fit_transform(X)
RF.fit(X, y)
```

Reference here: [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html)