# Scikit grid search for KNN regression ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement grid search for selecting best parameters for KNN regression using Scikit learn.
Particularly what I am trying to do:

```
parameters = [{'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'], 'n_neighbors': [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]}]
clf = GridSearchCV(neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(), parameters)
clf.fit(features, rewards)
```

Unfortunately I am getting ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.

```
/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in fit(self, X, y, **params)
705                           " The params argument will be removed in 0.15.",
706                           DeprecationWarning)
--> 707         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
708 
709 

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
491                     X, y, base_estimator, parameters, train, test,
492                     self.scorer_, self.verbose, **self.fit_params)
--> 493                 for parameters in parameter_iterable
494                 for train, test in cv)
495 

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __call__(self, iterable)
515         try:
516             for function, args, kwargs in iterable:
--> 517                 self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
518 
519             self.retrieve()

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in dispatch(self, func, args, kwargs)
310         """
311         if self._pool is None:
--> 312             job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
313             index = len(self._jobs)
314             if not _verbosity_filter(index, self.verbose):

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __init__(self, func, args, kwargs)
134         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
135         # arguments in memory
--> 136         self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
137 
138     def get(self):

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in fit_grid_point(X, y, base_estimator, parameters, train, test, scorer, verbose, loss_func, **fit_params)
309             this_score = scorer(clf, X_test, y_test)
310         else:
--> 311             this_score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
312     else:
313         clf.fit(X_train, **fit_params)

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.pyc in score(self, X, y)
320 
321         from .metrics import r2_score
--> 322         return r2_score(y, self.predict(X))
323 
324 

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.pyc in r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
2181 
2182     """
-> 2183     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred)
2184 
2185     if len(y_true) == 1:

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.pyc in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred)
 59         Estimated target values.
 60     """
---> 61     y_true, y_pred = check_arrays(y_true, y_pred)
 62 
 63     if y_true.ndim == 1:

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_arrays(*arrays, **options)
231                 else:
232                     array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype)
--> 233                 _assert_all_finite(array)
234 
235         if copy and array is array_orig:

/Users/zikesjan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in _assert_all_finite(X)
 25     if (X.dtype.char in np.typecodes['AllFloat'] and not np.isfinite(X.sum())
 26             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
---> 27         raise ValueError("Array contains NaN or infinity.")
 28 
 29 

ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.
```

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895502/scikit-learn-valueerror-array-contains-nan-or-infinity) I have already tried to use following line with fit instead of the one that is above:

```
clf.fit(np.asarray(features).astype(float), np.asarray(rewards).astype(float))
```

Then based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320456/scikit-nan-or-infinity-error-message) I have tried even this:

```
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(np.asarray(features).astype(float))
transformed_features = scaler.transform(np.asarray(features).astype(float))
clf.fit(transformed_features, rewards)
```

But unfortunately without any success. So I would like to ask if anybody have some idea where possibly the problem can be and how can I make my code work.

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT:**

I have found out that I am not getting this error in case when I have only following parameters:

```
parameters = [{'weights': ['uniform'], 'n_neighbors': [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]}]
```

So it seems like the problem is in case when weights=distance. Does anybody have an idea why?

There has appeared one more problem related to this about which I'm asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260000/scikit-learn-griddearchcv-python-stops-working-when-n-jobs1).

**EDIT 2:**

If I run my code with logging set on debug, I am getting following warning:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/regression.py:160: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
y_pred[:, j] = num / denom
```

So there is clearly problem with division by zero. So my question is why there scikit divides by 0 on line 160 in regression.py?

Comment: Does `numpy.isnan(features).any()` or `numpy.isnan(rewards)` yield `True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to what you have tried, you can also see if

```
import numpy as np
features = np.nan_to_num(features)
rewards = np.nan_to_num(rewards)
```

This sets all non-numeric values in your arrays to `0`, and should at least make your algorithm run, unless the error occurs somewhere internal to the algorithm. Make sure there aren't to many non-numeric entries in your data, as setting them all to 0 may cause strange biases in your estimates.

If this is not the case, and you are using `weights='distance'`, then please check whether any of the train samples are identical. This will cause a division by zero in inverse distance.

If inverse distances are the cause of division by zero, you can circumvent this by using your own distance function, e.g.

```
def better_inv_dist(dist):
    c = 1.
    return 1. / (c + dist)
```

and then use `'weights': better_inv_dist`. You may need to adapt the constant `c` to the right scale. In any case it will avoid division by zero as long as `c > 0`.

Comment: I have tried this, but it did not work with np.nan_to_num either. I'm still getting ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity.

Comment: OK, that rules out problems in the data you input. But it may cause e.g. division by zero somewhere on the way. Have you tried %debug in IPython to see what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Yes you're right. There is probably some division by zero, for more details see edit 2 in the post. But the question remains: Why there scikit divides by 0?

Comment: It looks like internally the weights may be set to 0. Could you check `'weights':['distance']` only in your grid search?

Comment: How many samples do you have? If this doesn't explode your memory, could you please check `from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances` then `distances = euclidean_distances(features, features)` and then report whether `(distances == 0.).any()` reports `True` ?

Comment: Or, asked in a different way, are there any two lines in `features` that are identical?

Comment: Yes you are right I had some of the features identical, which has cased the division by 0. For dataset without two or more same features grid search works correctly. Unfortunately I have in my dataset features more than once (even with different reward value) on purpose. I'll probably have to do some check in my code and use 2 different parameter dicts based on if I have duplicity in features. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Great. I learnt something new here, too. I made a last update to my answer proposing a slightly modified custom inverse distance that may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with KNN regression on scikit-learn. I was using weights='distance' and that led to infinite values while computing the predictions (but not while fitting the KNN model i.e. learning appropriate KD Tree or Ball Tree). I switched to weights='uniform' and the program ran to completion correctly, indicating the supplied weight function was the problem. If you want to use distance-based weights, supply a custom-weight function that doesn't explode to infinity at zero distance as indicated in eickenberg's answer.