# Is there a branch of SKLearn with robust parallelism?

Tags: machine-learning, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

The SKLearn machine learning library is extremely fragile when using it's built-in parallelism (setting n_jobs=-1). Are there patches, branches, or alternatives here?

**Examples of Multicore fragility:**

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5115
- https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/138
- [scikit-learn's GridSearchCV stops working when n_jobs>1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260000/scikit-learns-gridsearchcv-stops-working-when-n-jobs1)

Comment: What do you mean with fragile? I think it is very stable (Linux) and i think it is used by many people without any problems at all. (There might be problems with OS X).

Comment: When using n_jobs > 1 with GridSearchCV sklearn tends to have memory issues and segfaults are common.

Comment: @sascha I've added a few examples of this documented behavior

Comment: As i thought, most of these are only a problem on OS X (which i don't use; but maybe you do). I got no problems on Linux + python3 (and i used it a lot). I don't think there is an alternative, as i think, if it would be so easy to make it work, the sklearn-devs would have done it. I had never a segfault and regarding memory problems, there is no unexplained behaviour for me (of course some models need a copy of the data; and there is the infamous pre_dispatch  parameter).