# GridSearchCV: ValueError - self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying out different regressors of **Scikit Learn** on a dataset of mine and I'm using **GridSearchCV** as a method of finding the best parameters possible. Everything was running smoothly (it ran on *Lasso*, *SVR*, *Random Trees* among other regression techniques with no problem) until deciding to experiment with the **KNeighborsRegressor**. As soon as I try to fit it on the Train dataset, it's giving me a Value Error.

Here's the critical snippet of my code:

```
# GridSearchCV
parameters = {
    'n_neighbors' : [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100],
    'p'           : [1, 2, 3]
}
knn = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsRegressor(), parameters)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Best parameter set
print('The best parameter set is: ' + str(knn.best_params_))
```

And here's the precise ValueError it outputs:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-907f16234c8f> in <module>
      5 }
      6 knn = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsRegressor(), parameters)
----> 7 knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
      8 # Best parameter set
      9 print('The best parameter set is: ' + str(knn.best_params_))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, 
groups, **fit_params)
    720                 return results_container[0]
    721 
--> 722             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    723 
    724         results = results_container[0]
```

I basically applied the same logic on how I ran the other regression techniques using GridSearchCV, only changed the parameters matrix and the regressor passed in as a parameter (KNeighborsRegressor) in this case.

**EDIT:** Just to make it clear that I'm dealing with a purely numerical data, I'm including snippets of the two sets parsed into the `fit()` function.

**X_train**
[image: X_train]

**y_train** - contains the values of the target attribute we're supposed to predict
[image: y_train]

Comment: whats p =3 ? I know that 1 is manhattan dist, and 2 is eucliean dist. Could you remove 3 from the param list? And that is not the whole error message.

Comment: In general, p denotes the order of the Minkovski distance. Unfortunately, getting rid of the entire line " 'p' : [1, 2, 3]) " didn't make any change, let alone just removing 3. And believe me, that is the entire error message, not sure if that might be due to me using Jupyter Notebook or not.

Comment: Does your dataset have categorical values? If it is a pandas dataframe. You might need to convert them to floats or something.

Comment: Everything non-numerical is already converted into integers and floats by the time I have to run the critical piece of code above.

Comment: Are there any nans?

Comment: None. All _NaNs_ from the original dataset were imputed with the **mean** values from their respective columns. Moreover, the entire Training went through **normalization** (scaling to unit norm) during the preprocessing phase. In short, the `X_train` dataset I'm passing to the `fit()` function is completely made of **numeric values**.

Comment: I edited my original post with snippets of the two datasets, just for clarity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249212/scikit-grid-search-for-knn-regression-valueerror-array-contains-nan-or-infinity this is similar question  but the value error is stated unlike yours. Well this sounds lame could you remove n_neigbours = 100.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?